# How to filter out caught exceptions in VS Diagnostic Tools?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My program constantly checks if a series of servers is online. If a server is not online, I get a HttpRequestException which is immediately caught, but still shows up under exceptions in Diagnostic Tools. This results in the exceptions list constantly being filled by thousands of these exceptions making it impossible to see if any real exception happens.

How do I make it show only uncaught exceptions?

Edit: Not a duplicate of [How to force visual studio debugger to skip specific exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518080/how-to-force-visual-studio-debugger-to-skip-specific-exceptions) that one's about breaking on exceptions and has nothing to do with Diagnostic Tools.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force visual studio debugger to skip specific exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518080/how-to-force-visual-studio-debugger-to-skip-specific-exceptions)

Comment: @Liam that one is about breaking on exceptions and doesn't even concern Diagnostic Tools.

Comment: What does "diagnostic tools" mean? How are these not Visual Studio?

Comment: @Liam they are a part of Visual Studio, just not the part discussed in that other question. Among other things you can see a list of exceptions in the Diagnostic Tools window while debugging. They show up there even if they are caught by your code and unselected in Exception Settings.